# Bayesian number guessing

Tags: probability, self-study, bayesian, multiarmed-bandit

This is a personal learning exercise:

Suppose an agent knows the range of values that a number (N) can take  but is only given feedback about how right or wrong he is after he makes a guess (os given a reward of zero or some higher value reflecting how accurate his estimate is). And after 30 trials this number (N) will change, so the agent's belief needs to be constantly reevaluated. N is drawn from a normal distribution with a mean of 20 and std of 5.

Can you expand in detail on how such a problem may be solved using Bayesian updating (with conjugate distributions).

It would be great if you also provide pseudocode for your answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below is a very simple Bayesian process.  I think that in order to get to an answer that is closer to what you want, you will need to specify the function that translates the guess into the measure of closeness.  The measure I used here is the simple 1 if the guess within a tolerance distance of the true answer and 0 otherwise.

````r
Nmin <- 0
Nmax <- 45
Nmean <- 20
Nsd <- 5
tol <- 4

# https://github.com/bertcarnell/truncateddist
require(truncateddist)

# assume that N is an integer
# assume that the function returns 1 if the guess is within +-tol, 0 otherwise

response <- function(N, guess, tol)
{
  ifelse(N < guess + tol & N > guess - tol, 1, 0)
}

guess <- function()
{
  # random guessing
  floor(runif(1, Nmin, Nmax + 1))
}

update <- function(priors, data)
{
  result <- priors * data / sum(priors * data)
  if (any(is.na(result)))
  {
    warning("no update")
    return(priors)
  }
  return(result)
}

create_data <- function(response, x, tol)
{
  index <- Nmin:Nmax
  sapply(index, function(z) {
    if (z < x- tol) return(abs(response-1))
    else if (z >= x - tol & z <= x  + tol) return(response)
    else if (z > x + tol) return(abs(response - 1))
    else stop("error")
  })
}

N <- floor(truncateddist::rtnorm(1, Nmean, Nsd, Nmin, Nmax + 1))
priors <- rep(1/(Nmax - Nmin + 1), times = (Nmax - Nmin + 1))
posteriors <- priors
plot(Nmin:Nmax, priors, type = "h")
for (i in 1:30)
{
  x <- guess()
  y <- response(N, x, tol)
  data <- create_data(y, x, tol)
  posteriors <- update(posteriors, data)
}
plot(Nmin:Nmax, posteriors, type = "h", main = paste0("Truth = ", N))
```
````

Comment: Thank you! I really appreciate it.